# Retrieve Page Layout Assignment using package.xml in SFDX

Tags: deployment, salesforce, variable-assignment, profile

I'm trying run sfdx:...retrieve using package.xml profiles, record types and page layouts. Retrieve is working as designed, but Page Layout Assignment is not getting retrieved.
 is not getting created in the package.

```
<types>
   <members>MyProfile</members>
   <name>Profile</name>
</types>
<types>
   <members>Task.TaskRecordType</members>
   <name>RecordType</name>
</types>
<types>
   <members>Task-TaskRTypeLayout</members>
   <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

Based on the articles it should be created for this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using ANT migration tool and it worked. I retrieved all profiles, record types and Page layouts. It retrieved layout assignments as well.

Give it a try.

Here is my package.xml

*
        Layout
    
    
        *
        Profile
    
    
        *
        RecordType
    
    52.0